# How do you use potions?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I am out of Skyloft and am trying to restore my hearts with the potion in my pouch but I have tried several things and nothing seems to be working.

I am not much of a gamer and could use all the help I can get.

Comment: What game is this?

Comment: Skyward Sword?  Maybe?

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe - the other question is more about equipping stuff rather than drinking potions.

Comment: @KatieK Considering you need to equip the bottle in order to drink from it, I think that if it's not a dupe now, you just have to add "then press A to drink a potion" to the other answer to make it one. Oh wait, it already contains that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use potions in Skyward Sword, hold down <kbd>-</kbd>, then point the Wiimote to your potion, then release <kbd>-</kbd>.

Once you have your potion out, just press <kbd>A</kbd>.  Link will chug that red magic and you'll heal those precious hearts.

If you're running out of potions, just take a seat on a chair, tree stump, or any other chair-like object that brings up a prompt, and you'll slowly fill your hearts as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you press the `-` button the Wii controller, you will take out your current item from your pouch.

If you hold the `-` key, it will show you all of the items you have in your pouch.

There are other ways to restore your hearts while your in Skyloft. You can sit on a bench, or you can slash around in bushes and find hearts.